# Fill values for mvc dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Pets, new SelectList(ViewBag.Pets, "key", "value"), new { @class = "type1 newdrop" })
```

I'm newbie in mvc development. Using the above line of code, I'm getting the dropdown list but only with `2` as value.

How can I fill the dropdownlist to all values lower than `2`, including `0`? I want the selected item to be `2`

```
 ViewBag.Pets = Constants.MaxP.Where( x => x.Key == someId); // the someId is for sure one of the below key numbers
```

where

```
  public static Dictionary<int, int>   MaxP = new Dictionary<int, int>(){
                {12, 2}, {13, 2}, {14, 2}, {15, 2}, {16, 2}, {17, 2}, {18, 2}
            };
```

Comment: you need to show us how you put value to your ViewBag.Pets

Comment: @FlorinM, Why all of your dictionary values are same (2)?

Comment: @Ram For the moment all ids have the same (2), but in the future they will be changed for sure, that's why I thought to use a Dictionnary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn your dictionary into a collection of `SelectListItem` like this:

```
int a = Constants.Maxp.FirstOrDefualt(x => x.Key == SomeID).Value;

List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();

for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    lst.Add(new SelectListItem(){
        Text = i.ToString(),
        Value = i.ToString()
    });
}

ViewBag.Pets = lst;
```

And then in your View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Pets, ViewBag.Pets, new { @class = "type1 newdrop" })
```

Where `x.pets` is the ID that matches the `Key`

Comment: Ah in that case just swap the condition to Value.. see edit

Comment: But I do want only for a specific KEY ( Id ), Shouldn't I use .Where ( x => x.key == someid ) ? What if not all the ids have only (2) as value, but different values? The example  you gave me isn't working

Comment: Yeah you can add further expressions into the Where clause.

Comment: Then save it as a constant, If you need values less then 2 you can't get around not using a hard coded 2. Learn when and when not to use magic numbers.

Comment: @Florin M. I just want to know how you populate your variable MaxP if you are saying you don't want hardcoded values? Maybe if you show us how you get values of your dictionary, we can give you better solutions.

Comment: If I put ' < 2 ' , I guess the value 2 isn't taken in consideration. I specified that I need the value (2) to be the selected item in my drop down list

Comment: I do get this error: does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>, I tried also with: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Pets, (SelectListItem)ViewBag.Pets, new { @class = "type1 newdrop" })

Answer (score 0):

```
var certainKey = 15;
var certainValue = 2;
```

To fill `dropdownlist` with all items with `key less than certainKey`

```
 ViewBag.Pets = Constants.MaxP.Where( x => x.Key < certainKey);
```

To fill `dropdownlist` with all items with `value less than certainValue`

```
 ViewBag.Pets = Constants.MaxP.Where( x => x.Value < certainValue);
```

To fill `dropdownlist` with the items with `key equal with certainKey` and `value less than certainValue`

```
 ViewBag.Pets = Constants.MaxP.Where( x => x.Key == certainKey && x.Value < certainValue);
```

**For logical and functional:**

- In a **`Dictionary`** **`Key` (id) should be unique** and **`Value` can be repetitious**.
- In a **`SelectList`** **`Value` (id) should be unique** and **`Text` can be repetitious**.
- Finally in the `dropdownlist` list you **should** use a `SelectList` then when you are using a `dictionary` for your `dropdownlist`, you should create a `SelectList` base on your `Dicatinary`. You are doing that and the convert schema is like this:

> - `Dicatinary` **Key** >>>> `SelectList` **Value**
> - `Dictionary` **Value** >> `SelectList` **Text**

Now decide with condition you should use in your dictionary selection to reach the goal.

---

**EDIT:**

Create a `Selectlist` from a `Dictinary` and set *default selected* value as `Max value`:

```
Dictionary<int,int> myDictionary = GetDictionary();
var pets=new SelectList(myDictionary, "key","value", myDictionary.Max(x => x.Key));
```

Pass the filled `selectList` to view

```
ViewBag.Pets = pets;
```

In View:

```
@{
  var myPets = ViewBag.Pets as Dictionary<int,int>;
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Pets, myPets, new { @class = "type1 newdrop" })
```

Now you just need write `GetDictionary()` method codes base on your application logic to create an appropriate dictionary of data.

Comment: I want to fill with the VALUES < 2, but only for a certain ID ( key ), What if not all the ids have only (2) as value, but different values?

Comment: I don't like using hardcoded values in code. If I change all the 2 values in dictionary, I must changed them here, not good

Comment: @FlorinM. you explaned yor problem by some numbers and i wrote some conditions base on your numbers, you can easlly replace numbers with variables!!! I do that in your my answer.

Comment: So let say I declare var certainKey = 15. Why I do still need to hardcode the certainValue? Why I can get it in another way if I do know the key? Why to declare both them hardcoded ?

Comment: You haven't told us what 2 is, how are we supposed to know how to generate it lol?!?

Comment: @RyanSearle Sorry my mistake. I'm newbie in development, don't get angry on me ...

Comment: Sorry for getting wound up, If you let us know where the 2 comes from we will be more than happy to help.

Comment: the 2 value is the VALUE from the dictionnary for a specified ID ( that someId )

Comment: so in this case someId = 2?

Comment: someID can be 12, 13, ... , 18 ( the KEYS from the dictionnary ) and the 2 represents the value for the given key. I gave an example with only 2 values, but in the future they will be changed. The someId is stored in a variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121602/discussion-between-florin-m-and-ryan-searle).

Comment: @FlorinM. I edited my answer with additional guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we typically populate dropdownlist.

For example you create a class for your items to be popluated on your dropdown:

```
public class MaxP
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then on your action in controller, you populate your selectlist like this:

```
var list = new List<MaxP>();
list.Add(new MaxP { Key = 12, Value = 2 });
list.Add(new MaxP { Key = 13, Value = 2 });
list.Add(new MaxP { Key = 14, Value = 2 });

ViewBag.Pets = new SelectList(list, "Key", "Value", null);
```

And in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Pets, (SelectList)ViewBag.Pets, new { @class = "type1 newdrop" });
```

Take note that, the text that will be shown in your dropdownlist are "2". And if it is selected the value you will get will be the 'Key', which on our example are 12,13, and 14.

Hope it is clear. It can be complicated from a beginner's point of view, but that's ok we all been there. But I encourage you to start doing the basic and your good to go. Please start your learning with the basic. Here's a good starting point: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part1

*code not tested, but I hope you get the point, happy learning.*